# Replace words from a string using python

Tags: python

```
import re

fp1 = open('stopwords.txt','r')
stop = fp1.readline()
#print(stop)

def passstopwords(getstopwords):
    stopword = getstopwords
    #print(stopword)
    fp = open('read1.txt', 'r')
    line = fp.readline
    while line:
        line = fp.readline()
        print(getstopwords)
        line = re.sub(getstopwords, r'', line)
        print(line)
    fp.close()
    return;

passstopwords(stop)
```

The output that I get is the same line, without any changes. However, it works fine if  I write `'somestring'` instead of  `'getstopwords'`.

Comment: Please correct the function's indentation.

Comment: Yes, please.  The script as given doesn't run because it isn't indented correctly.  Also, what are you using for input?

Comment: please use better parameter names. that would make you code more understandable. `getstopswords` feels like a function that i will call to get the stop words. use something like `stop_word_pattern` if its a pattern.

Comment: could you please post an example content of the variable getstopwords

Comment: Sorry for naive coding. I am passing string through variable, which I am reading from another file. That file consists of words- is, and, the etc. Each line has only one word in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Inputfile is SAMPLE.TXT with the following content**

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets con
```

**The stopwords.txt is**

```
Lorem
simply
book
printing
```

**The code is:**

```
import re
fp1 = open('stopwords.txt','r')
lisOfStopWords = fp1.readlines()
fp1.close()

def passstopwords(lisOfStopWords):
    stopwords = "|".join([x.strip() for x in lisOfStopWords])
    print("Stopwords:" + stopwords)
    fp = open('SAMPLE.TXT', 'r')
    stopWordPattern = r"%(stopwords)s" % {'stopwords' : stopwords}
    for line in fp.readlines():
        print("ORIGINAL:" + line.strip())
        line = re.sub(stopWordPattern, r'', line)
        print("REPLACED:"+ line)
    fp.close()
    return;

passstopwords(lisOfStopWords)
```

**The output is:**

```
Stopwords:Lorem|simply|book|printing
ORIGINAL:Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
REPLACED: Ipsum is  dummy text of the  and typesetting industry.

ORIGINAL:Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
REPLACED: Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,

ORIGINAL:when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
REPLACED:when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type

ORIGINAL:specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
REPLACED:specimen . It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap

ORIGINAL:into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
REPLACED:into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

ORIGINAL:It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets con
REPLACED:It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets con
```

As you see `Lorem` or `simply` or `book` or `printing` will be replaced.

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is I am passing values through a variable called "stopword"

Comment: @NameetNameet could you pleas paste your complete code?

Comment: how does stopwords look just stopword1\nstopword2?

Comment: It is a text file and formatted as below:
is
the
and

Comment: And i got the answer. All I had to do is use stop = stop.strip()  and then pass is it. It works completely fine now. Thank you all.

Comment: @NameetNameet would be nice if you give me some points cause my answer is correct to. And its very fast cause creating first an regular expression of all stopwords .. and then replacing it line by line perhaps i could replace it in one time, too

Comment: What points am not getting you, sorry. Yes, it would be if code can run faster. Give your gmail id, we can chat there

Comment: @NameetNameet you can upvote my post ... and later you can select it as helpful - right answer.

Comment: @NameetNameet just enter this chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105347/chat

Comment: @NameetNameet Here is the faq to accept an answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers .. and btw hello to stackoverflow